# Laravel: What is the proper response of a controller to an ajax request?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am having a problem returning a proper response to an ajax request I made.

Basically, I have a `checkbox` which when `changed()` fires an ajax with `csrf-token` to be accepted in `POST method`, the changes reflected on the database is successful but the error starts on returning the "status" of the process to the ajax.

Heres my controller method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
      $result = ItemPrice::toggleRestockable($id);

      return $result;
  }
```

`$result` is the output of `DB::update() method`

The ajax goes to `error:` block with `Internal Server Error 500` regardless whether the query was a success or not.

The `responseText` of `data` variable in ajax was mainly:

```
(1/1) UnexpectedValueException
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

Now I know I am returning `boolean` or technically an integer because it was a result of `DB::update()` which returns the number of rows affected by the `update`.

**Now how could I properly return a response that an ajax can understand?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $result = ItemPrice::toggleRestockable($id);
  return Response::json(['success' => $result], 200);
}
```

Comment: thats exactly what im doing right now which is working so far

Answer (score 4):

Create one base ApiController abstract class and extend it in your any controller. so you no need to prepare response obj for success and error in every function and every controller. you just call function. example given here.

// Base **ApiController**

```
 abstract class ApiController extends Controller
    {

        /**
         * Make standard response with some data
         *
         * @param object|array $data Data to be send as JSON
         * @param int $code optional HTTP response code, default to 200
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        protected function respondWithData($data, $code = 200)
        {
            return Response::json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $data
            ], $code);
        }


        /**
         * Make standard successful response ['success' => true, 'message' => $message]
         *
         * @param string $message Success message
         * @param int $code HTTP response code, default to 200
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        protected function respondSuccess($message = 'Done!', $code = 200)
        {
            return Response::json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => $message
            ], $code);
        }

        /**
         * Make standard response with error ['success' => false, 'message' => $message]
         *
         * @param string $message Error message
         * @param int $code HTTP response code, default to 500
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
         */
        protected function respondWithError($message = 'Server error', $code = 500)
        {
            return Response::json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $message
            ], $code);
        }
```

**How to use functions of base class. see example here**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    try{
      $result = ItemPrice::toggleRestockable($id);
    return $this->respondWithData($result);
      }catch(Exception $e){
      return $this->respondWithError($e->getMessage());
    }
  }
```

**how to extend base controller into your controller**

```
class TestController extends ApiController {}
```

Answer (score 3):

JsonResponse is the class you need.

```
return response()->json($result);
```

using helpers. Use ->toArray() on $result if dealing with collections.

Answer (score 1):

```
return $result;
```

will return the object of data, there are multiple ways to handle this depending on the return type of your toggle function.

The Typical way to handle an AJAX request is to save data and return the status and message.

in your scenario, I could use a response to JSON

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $status  = 500;
        $message = 'An Un expected error Occured';
        try {
            $result = ItemPrice::toggleRestockable($id);
            //assuming toggleRestockable function will return  bool
            if ($result) {
                $status  = 200;
                $message = 'Successfully Updated';
            }
            return response()->json(['status' => $status, 'message' => $message]);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 500, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

This way of doing works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
      {
        $this->validate($request, [
       //some of your data =>'required|min:4'; <-your rules
                       ]);
          $result = ItemPrice::findOrFail($id);
          //something request;
          $result->save();

          return response()->json(['result'=>$result]);
      }


and you can call your error by using this
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif


i hope it will helps you a lot :)
```